# MDF File does not show up in Visual Studio 2015 Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

When I rebuild the app and run it, it creates the mdf file in the AppData location but it does not show up in the AppData folder under solution explorer. If I right click AppData in solution explorer I can see the mdf file. What's the deal?

Web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewUserContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NewUser.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UserDetails.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image]

Comment: Check the .csproj and make sure they are not excluded

Comment: This is a brand new project, how would it have gotten excluded?

Comment: IIRC, that folder is excluded automatically

Comment: Not in any of my previous projects, it always seems to be included.

Comment: It does not add it automatically in this project. It's not in the includes and won't automatically add it. I can't manually add it because if I delete it from the solution explorer it doesn't add it back after rebuild.

Comment: I don't recall off the top of my head but aren't most files in the `App_Data` folder hidden?  One of the buttons at the top of the solution explorer should be to show hidden files.